# Delete only specific int values from int array in UserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I made a `like` button on a book page.
When I press a `like` button, the image of the button changes.
The page number is stored in an Int Array in UserDefaults.

But when I cancelled the like, page numbers stored in Int Array UserDefaults should be deleted.

How can I delete a specific number inside an Int Array in UserDefaults?

```
@objc func likeBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if sender.isSelected == false {
                sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "fill-heart"), for: .normal)

                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.bookPage, forKey: "\(self.bookNo ?? "")")

self.likePageArr.append(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "\(self.bookNo ?? "")") as! Int)

                var likePageArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "\(self.bookNo ?? "")Arr") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()

                    UserDefaults.standard.set(self.likePageArr, forKey: "\(self.bookNo ?? "")Arr")

                sender.isSelected = true

            } else if sender.isSelected == true {
                sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "none-heart"), for: .normal)
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "\(self.bookNo ?? "")")

                var likePageArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "\(self.bookNo ?? "")Arr") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()

                likePageArray.remove(at: likePageArray.index(of: self.bookPage) ?? 0)

//i need delete self.bookPage in likePageArray

                sender.isSelected = false
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why dont you create a grobal variable array which get the value from UserDefaults?If you need to change the value,you can just edit the array and then save it to UserDefaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already removed the value from the array here:

```
likePageArray.remove(at: likePageArray.index(of: self.bookPage) ?? 0)
```

Now, you just need to re-write the array back to `UserDefaults` (like you did before):

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.likePageArr, forKey: "\(self.bookNo ?? "")Arr")
```